# What does this lyric mean?

Tags: song-lyrics

I was listening to 悲しい色やね by Ueda Masaki. I was able to pick up the lyrics, but there are certain phrases that I cannot translate. In the main melody part, I was able to pick up

```
ほーみーたい
大阪ベイブルース
```

In the first line, I can understand that たい means "want to", but I have no idea what ほーみー means. It does not seem to be an onomatopoeia. I searched it on google, and it suggests some kind of musical instrument, but that does not seem to make sense. Then, a friend of mine told me that there is a word like that in Okinawan dialect, but was not sure. If that is right, what does it mean? Will it make sense with "want to"?

In the second line, I know that this is a song about Osaka, and Osaka people often like to have particular western people as their mascot. For example, people were happy with the Colonel Sanders statue in Osaka, and they once threw him into a river. Can I consider ベイブルース (Babe Ruth) along the same line? But who is 大阪ベイブルース? It doesn't seem to just Babe Ruth himself, is it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is my favorite song.  Ask anything about it.

> 「ほーみーたい」 = "Hold me tight."

I know it sounds like 「ほーみーたい」 but that part is actually in "English".

> 「大阪ベイブルース」 = "Osaka Bay Blues".

The whole song takes place on a pier facing the Osaka Bay.  It is not "Osaka Babe Ruth", but I had a good laugh!

Comment: Song lyrics are often misheard even by native speakers, such as the famous "*'Scuse me, while I kiss this guy'*" line from [Jimmy Hendrix's *Purple Haze*](https://www.google.com/search?q=excuse+me+while+i+kiss+this+guy).  There's even [a website dedicated to misheard English-language song lyrics](http://www.kissthisguy.com/), which might be worth a laugh.  Once you start talking about songs in other languages, I'm sure the chances for hilarity increase exponentially.

Comment: 「ベーブ・ルース」って初めて聞いたとき「ベイ・ブルース」って切るのかなと思いました。「ブルース・リー(Bruce Lee)」って初めて聞いたとき「ブルー・スリー(Blue Three)」って切るのかなと思いました。